# Functor for Choosing Between Two Functions

Tags: c++, function-pointers, functor

Googling for C++ functor syntax brings a lot of different results and I don't think I see what need in any of them.  Some use templates, some use a single class, others multiple, and still others use structs instead.  I'm never sure what specific elements I need for what I want to do.  So now, what I want to do:

I have two functions.  They both take the exact same parameters, but are named differently and will return a different result, though the return type is also the same, e.g.,

`unsigned foo1(char *start, char *end);`
`unsigned foo2(char *start, char *end);`

I just want to choose which function to call depending on the value of a Boolean variable.  I could just write a predicate to choose between the two, but that doesn't seem an elegant solution.  If this were C, I'd use a simple function pointer, but I've been advised they don't work well in C++.

Edit:  Due to restrictions beyond my control, in this scenario, I cannot use C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `std::function`:

```
std::function<unsigned int(char*, char*)> func = condition ? foo1 : foo2;
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function signature

// ...

unsigned int result = func(start, end);
```

Also, function pointers work fine in C++:

```
auto func = condition ? foo1 : foo2;

unsigned int result = func(start, end);
```

But `std::function` is more flexible.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer.  I should have mentioned to begin with that I cannot use C++11 for this particular problem.  Your answer will be very useful for those who do not have my constraint, so I thank you.

Comment: @Eric I only used `auto` as an abreviation. If you don't have `auto`, you can do `unsigned int(*func)(char*, char*) = condition ? foo1 : foo2;`.