# functor: wrapping std::function in a class

Tags: c++, functor

Say I am writing a library that should provide some default computing (function), but enables the user to provide his own, at compile-time.
For instance, say the library provides a function that returns his argument times 3, but the user can provide his own function.

Consider the following program (to be seen as a MWE):

```
float myFunction( float v )  // the function the user needs
{
    return v*2;
}

int main()
{
    FuncWrapper f;
    cout << "default: " << f(2) << endl; // should print "6"

    f.AssignFunction( myFunction );
    cout << "now is: " << f(2) << endl; // should print "4"
}
```

So I have build a functor `FuncWrapper` that wraps a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), as proposed [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12993980/193789):

```
struct FuncWrapper
{
    std::function<float(float)> foo; // the function used

    float def( float v ) // the default behaviour member function definition
    {
        return v*3;
    }

    float operator()( float v ) // call of function
    {
        return foo(v);
    }

    void AssignFunction( float (*uf)(float) ) { foo = uf; }

// constructor: initializes to default function
    FuncWrapper() : foo(&FuncWrapper::def) {}
};
```

On my machine (gcc 4.6.3) with `-std=c++0x`, I get non human-readable error messages, as stated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/357223/193789). For conveniency, the code is [runnable here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85c18828a804a7f9). Seems to be gcc 4.8, and it doesn't like the constructor (among other errors...):

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'FuncWrapper::FuncWrapper()':
main.cpp:27:64: error: no matching function for call to 'std::function<float(float)>::function(float (FuncWrapper::*)(float))'
```

Why is this assignment illegal ? I have [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20%5Bfunctor%5D%20wrapping) for this topic, maybe wrong keyword, but didn't find anything relevant.

Any clue? Or a simpler solution, maybe without `std::function` but with a function pointer?

Comment: FuncWrapper::def need to be static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example code, you try to assign your member function to a `std::function` with signature `float(float)`. These two are not compatible, since the member function has a different calling convention: it requires a `this` argument.

Make your default function `static` to avoid this.

Comment: (the function that should be static is `def`, incidentally)

Comment: Was so simple!!! I can't believe I spend so much time on this... Thanks. (will accept, but need to wait 4 minutes???)

Comment: @kebs Really good answers take time to write. You have to wait 10 minutes before you can accept an answer to give good answers a chance to be picked over fast answers. [Details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-10-minutes-after-asking-the-question).